# Is dpi relevant when figure is saved as PDF?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, dpi

If I am saving figures as PDF, is `dpi` still relevant? For example, in the following code

```py
import pylab

pylab.savefig('./test_200.pdf', dpi = 200)
pylab.savefig('./test_2000.pdf', dpi = 2000)
```

does `dpi` make a difference?

To me it does not make a difference at least in resolution, I have zoomed in as much as I can and the two figures look the same

[image: dpi]

Is it possible that there are any underlying difference or simply no difference? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note: using `import pylab` is [strongly discouraged](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html?highlight=pylab#module-pylab), consider using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it *will* make a difference as soon as anything gets converted into a raster image, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_rasterization_zorder(0)

ax.scatter([0,1,2],[3,4,5], zorder=-1)
ax.scatter([0,1,2],[4,5,6], zorder=2)

plt.savefig('/tmp/test_20.pdf', dpi=20)
plt.savefig('/tmp/test_2000.pdf', dpi=2000)
```

Note how the lower row of scatter points is rasterized (due to its `zorder` being kept below the "rasterization threshold", as defined via `ax.set_rasterization_zorder`. The figure saved with 20 dpi now looks like this:

[image: Low rasterization example]

Comment: I see, so anything that has a `zorder` below 0 in this case will be rasterized, but how is this feature usually used?

Comment: Usually, you'd be using a combination of raster and vector graphics whenever the data you're trying to plot is quite large or complicated, which can make vector graphics slow to render (they are rendering instructions, after all). Have you ever experienced smooth scrolling through a large PDF file of text & images and suddenly everything crawls to a stop for just one graphic? That's likely the culprit.

Comment: Another reason may be to try to confirm to certain standards - [PDF/A-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A), I'm looking at you - which e.g. forbid transparent objects and layers. Here you can "cheat" your way around this pitfall by "baking" your combined image content into a raster image, while still keeping your axes and text objects nicely rendered (and searchable within the PDF!).